# Как очистить буфер терминала в Vim 8?

Tags: linux, консоль, vim

Я открываю терминал в Виме (`:terminal`) и запускаю `yes`, который генерирует мне 10 000 строк скролбека. Как я могу удалить эти строки, чтобы они не занимали места в ОЗУ? `clear` просто перематывает скролбек вперёд, то есть делает ещё хуже.

Comment: А чем не нравится использование `tmux`? С табами, окнами и зумом.

Comment: Вопрос немного офтопный. Во-первых, последний раз, когда я пробовал, были конфликты между Тмуксом и Вимом. Во-вторых, в Виме мне удобнее работать.

Comment: 1. к программам linux и vim вопрос, конечно, не имеет вообще никакого отношения. 2. да и к консоли вряд ли — ведь скорее всего вы используете иксовый эмулятор тераминала, а не консоль. 3. вот его справку и почитайте. конечно, скорее всего, подобная фича не реализована, и максимум что можно сделать — указать меньшее количество информации, хранимой в буфере. например, у программы gnome-terminal это [настраиваемо](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57259/110559).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Нет, он имел в виду терминал, встроенный в Vim 8 версии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опция `termwinscroll`, контролирующая глубину скролла, [была добавлена](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/8c041b6b95f49f7383cf00e2036cf009b326fa8d#diff-aa095c2f3891d858d5cd11c202a83302) в Вим в патче `8.0.1712`:

```
                        *'termwinscroll'* *'twsl'*
'termwinscroll' 'twsl'  number  (default 10000)
            local to buffer
            {not available when compiled without the
            |+terminal| feature}
    Number of scrollback lines to keep.  When going over this limit the
    first 10% of the scrollback lines are deleted.  This is just to reduce
    the memory usage.  See |Terminal-Normal|.
```